# Trouble in understanding `use chroot` parameter in rsyncd.conf

Tags: rsync

`rsyncd.conf` has the following option for rsync daemon mode:

> **use chroot**
>
> If "use chroot" is true, the rsync daemon will chroot to
>   the "path" before starting the file transfer with the client. This has
>   the advantage of extra protection against possible implementation
>   security holes, but it has the disadvantages of requiring super-user
>   privileges, of not being able to follow symbolic links that are either
>   absolute or outside of the new root path, and of complicating the
>   preservation of users and groups by name (see below).
>
> As an additional
>   safety feature, you can specify a dot-dir in the module's "path" to
>   indicate the point where the chroot should occur. This allows rsync to
>   run in a chroot with a non-"/" path for the top of the transfer
>   hierarchy. Doing this guards against unintended library loading (since
>   those absolute paths will not be inside the transfer hierarchy unless
>   you have used an unwise pathname), and lets you setup libraries for
>   the chroot that are outside of the transfer. For example, specifying
>   "/var/rsync/./module1" will chroot to the "/var/rsync" directory and
>   set the inside-chroot path to "/module1". If you had omitted the
>   dot-dir, the chroot would have used the whole path, and the
>   inside-chroot path would have been "/".

I have trouble understanding the

> you can specify a dot-dir in the module's "path" to indicate the point where the chroot should occur. This allows rsync to run in a chroot with a non-"/" path for the top of the transfer hierarchy. Doing this guards against unintended library loading

part.

Does it mean that rsync (in daemon mode) tries to load libraries after calling `chroot()` system call? I tried to test this, example rsyncd.conf:

```
uid = 0
gid = 0
use chroot = yes

[backup]
path  = /home/minecraft/
read only = yes
```

Strace of rsync daemon obviosly shows chroot:

```
[pid 20018] geteuid()                   = 0
[pid 20018] chroot("/home/minecraft")   = 0
[pid 20018] chdir("/")                  = 0
[pid 20018] setgid(0)                   = 0
[pid 20018] setgroups(1, [0])           = 0
[pid 20018] setuid(0)                   = 0
[pid 20018] setresuid(-1, 0, -1)        = 0
[pid 20018] geteuid()                   = 0
```

but no attempts to load libraries after chroot() call.

Answer (score 0):

> unintended library loading

TLDR;

Rsyncd chroot mode protects against accidental loading of shared system/user libraries other than the ones you intended to use during the connection phase of rsync. Rsync cannot access and accidentally load what it is not allowed to access in the first place (ie. `/` hierarchy) due to your chroot (if defined correctly).

---

[How rsync works a practical overview](http://rsync.samba.org/how-rsync-works.html) gives us a bit of insight in what execution flow happens during connection phase in chroot mode.

> When a connection is received for a defined module the daemon forks a new child process to handle the connection. That child process then reads the rsyncd.conf file to set the options for the requested module, which may chroot to the module path and may drop setuid and setgid for the process. After that it will behave just like any other rsync server process adopting either a sender or receiver role.

I assume that `library` refers to binary system/user libraries (.so,.a). There are for instance old environmental variables such as eg. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and so on which could cause trouble when running `rsync`. We know from the [overview](http://rsync.samba.org/how-rsync-works.html) that `rsync` does the following:

> the daemon forks a new child process to handle the connection.

which means that if you have manipulated some environment variables or defined some specific variables in your eg. `$HOME/.bashrc` etc. then this could lead to unintended side effects such as `unintended library loading`.

[Here](http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html) is some interesting and insightful explanation how for instance `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` could lead to weird and unforeseen side effects.

> use chroot

Additionally, the main idea of this parameter is extra protection against possible implementation security holes. To a lesser extent also protecting against breaking in via `rsync`.

Comment: I updated the question. If I understand correctly, documentation says there is a protection from loading unwanted libraries *only* if you specify a "dot-dir" in path. Or maybe it's just my broken English :)

Comment: Yeah correct. If you define it without that then rsync can potentially read the rest of the path hierarchy seems with possible side-effects.

Comment: @SawashiroMiyuki Can you please accept the answer if finished? Thanks.